# Unable to download iOS app from App Store but works in Test Flight

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I have an app that has been on the App Store for a few months now with about 6 previous updates that have gone very smoothly. I use Test Flight to test the app on my device before submitting. This time around everything looked fine on Test Flight as usual so I went ahead and submitted the app for review. It was approved and the status switched to ready for sale, however, when I tried to download the App from the App Store it said it was unable to downlaoad again with the options to try again or done. I have tried it on numerous devices and it appears to be a problem for everyone, not just myself. This happens even though the same build worked great with Test Flight. Can anybody help? A lot of people have failed to download or update their app and it is affecting us a lot.

Comment: Try contacting the support team. They can help you in a better way in this situation than us.

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately they have not been able to respond yet. In the meantime everyone updating my app on the phone is having this problem. I am worried this may lead to uninstalls. Is there a quick fix like reverting back to the old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, i understand that you have checked several devices and all got the same installation issue.

But i think, it is important for you to know,

**You might face issue in installing app from App Store, with TestFlight build still installed in your device.**

Please try uninstalling the Test Flight build first and then install app from App Store.

Comment: I have deleted the Test Flight build before installing from the App Store. Something new that I noticed was that it looks like my provisioning profile is now inactive for some reason. I'm not sure when this would have happened. If I submitted the app with an invalid provisioning profile could it have passed review? Could this be a problem?

Comment: Although, it seems unreasonable, but now, with every other thing right, this seems to be the possible issue!

Comment: Upload a new version and request an expedited review. With Critical bug like yours, they should approve within one day.